# erro ao gerar o build do angular /material

Tags: php, laravel, angular, angular-material

Na hora que rodo o serve aparece esse erro e não carrega meus componentes fica exibindo o seguinte erro que não consigo solucionar:

> -Console- 
>   `main.ts:13 Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.
>       at new PathLocationStrategy (common.js:453)
>       at provideLocationStrategy (router.js:5533)
>       at _callFactory (core.js:21286)
>       at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21238)
>       at initNgModule (core.js:21168)
>       at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:21895)
>       at createNgModuleRef (core.js:21884)
>       at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:23715)
>       at >NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (core.js:24419)
>       at core.js:17765`

Arquivo `main.ts`

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import 'hammerjs';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Isso ajuda, https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF?

Comment: Obrigado. me ajudou muito.